# Woocommerce REST API https - Cannot Connect

Tags: wordpress, rest, ssl, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Connecting to WooCommerce API, HTTP have no problems.

When I change the permalinks from http to https then try to connect using the https url I get:

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

I have an SSL cert, so I'm not sure why it won't work?

Please help,

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Request: HTTP
[image]
[image]

[image]

HTTPS

[image: https postman req]

[image: https postman fail]
[image: woocommerce https]

Comment: Can you share the petition you're making? Also, it seems like you're not autenticating

Comment: @Skatox thanks.

See attached.

Comment: thanks a lot.now my site is https and my api hs already worked like a charm !

Comment: You can select my answer as the answer, so it helps me

Answer (score 3):

According to [WooCommerce REST API documentation](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https):

> Occasionally some servers may not parse the Authorization header
>   correctly (if you see a “Consumer key is missing” error when
>   authenticating over SSL, you have a server issue). In this case, you
>   may provide the consumer key/secret as query string parameters
>   instead.

Check that orders parameters are in the same order as examples, no space. Or I would use basic HTTPS authentication, that's how I comunicate using https:

```
https://localhost/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems it is an issue with SSL:

RESPONSE:
stdClass Object ( [body] => {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Consumer key is invalid."}]} [code] => 401 [headers] => Array ( [Date] => Mon, 24 Apr 2017 22:38:41 GMT [Server] => Apache/2.4.10 [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 ) )

Comment: Regenerate Consumer key and try to authenticate with both methods.